# Change database port (postgresql) in Mantis

Tags: php, mantis, php-pgsql

I'm using mantis, and i want to change the port of database, i tried

`$g_hostname      = '192.168.56.33:5533';`

But that didn't work.

Is there any way to change the default port of postgresql database configuration in mantis?

Comment: Are you sure that PostgreSQL is listening on the IP. I guess the default behaviour is to listen only at localhost.

Comment: I added an entry for mantis in pg_hba.conf.